# Using a promise in an Angular 7 directive?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, observable

In the "good old days" of AngularJS I had a nice directive on buttons and links which has shown me a load spinner during http requests.

Now I tried to rebuild this with Angular 7 now but I ran into problems. Hopefully, can somebody help please...

At first I have a prety simple httpInterceptor to emit events when a http-request starts and when its stops:

```
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';

import { LoadingService } from './loading.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoadingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private loadingService: LoadingService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        this.loadingService.onNotify(true)

        return next.handle(request)
                   .finally(() => { 
                       this.loadingService.onNotify(false) 
                    });
    }
}
```

This is working so far. Now I have created a service to handle the events:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject }  from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class LoadingService {
//  notify: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
    notify: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

    onNotify(event) {
        this.notify.next(true);
    }
}
```

... and finally my directive:

```
import { OnInit, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingService } from './loading.service';

@Directive({
    selector: '[loading]'
})
export class LoadingDirective {

    constructor(
        private element: ElementRef, 
        private renderer: Renderer2, 
        private loadingService: LoadingService
    ) {
        console.log("DIRECTIVE LOADING")
        this.renderer.addClass(this.element.nativeElement, "required");

        this.loadingService.notify.subscribe((result) => {
            console.log('result', result)
        })
    }
}
```

The problem is: it wont work! It is compiled successfully, but when a component which uses the [loading] tag is tried to be displayed, I get a console error:

```
ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
    resolvePromise http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3159:31
    resolvePromise http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3116:17
    scheduleResolveOrReject http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3218:17
    invokeTask http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2766:17
    ...
```

Why can't the promise not being resolved? Where is my mistake? I really hope that somebody of you has a solution for my problem.

Comment: I found the error by myself. I have forgotten to make the service known in to the module
 providers: [
  LoadingService
 ]